# How to set XTextTable name dynamically

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, uno

I can't find how to set the name property of a table.

```
//I create the table here and the default name is table1
XTextTable xTT = (XTextTable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextTable.class, oInt);
xTT.initialize(1, 1);
```

How do I proceed to change this name that was set by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the [XNamed](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/container/XNamed.html#setName) interface of `xTT` and call setName().

See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=41424.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to set the name by the code:
XNamed xNamed = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNamed.class, xTT);

xNamed.setName("name");